How to get rid of treated pine odour?
It’s treated LOSP and/or possibly CCA. Very strong kerosene chemical smell that is making me nasuseous. The wood was quite wet and oily when we started using it. I’ve done two coats of water based varnish.
What will make the smell go away? Is there anything else I could use to seal it more, over the varnish, to stop the odour?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I'm curious why you continued to use this wood for your project with the smell being so obnoxious, right from the start presumably? Was it simply that you'd bought it and you felt you had to use it? FWIW pressure-treated wood is even lower on the food chain than untreated construction wood for indoor projects and, when new especially, is not advisable for many purposes. People who are more cautious wouldn't even work with it indoors (as per the industry guidelines).

"Is the best I can do now just to wait, keep windows open, fan on?" I think so! "Is there anything else that would seal in the smell?" You're kind of stuck between a rock and a hard place here. If you'd started from the outset with the intention of sealing in the smell (which I think would have been an error anyway) you might have been able to seal in better but maybe not now. You could try to apply more of your finish if practical — the thicker a coat of anything the greater the sealing effect — but obviously this goes hand in hand with a change in appearance, which may be undesirable.

The smell will subside eventually, but for you and future readers, I’ll mention that interior pressure treated lumber is only appropriate for bottom plate on concrete, ground contact, or possibly in very damp locations (though the problem to be solved there is the dampness).

LOSP and CCA imply what I would call pressure treated lumber. Straight out of the home center/lumber yard, that stuff is oozing chemical treatment.  I usually let it sit a week on a concrete floor, usually the garage, turning it every couple days perhaps more often. This allows those chemicals to evaporate and to some extend, be absorbed by the concrete floor.  This sometimes will also show if any of the boards are developing a warp. Many times a noticeable difference in weight is observed after a week of drying out.
In this instance because a finish was already applied, it's going to be more difficult to get that odor and residual chemical out.

Thanks, but missed the boat on letting it air/dry. It’s already inside and has been varnished. (I know it’s intended for outdoor use). Is the best I can do now just to wait, keep windows open, fan on?
Is there anything else that would seal in the smell?

If it's possible to set the item outside that would help.
